# rails - setting up linkedin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, linkedin-api

bit of a silly question but how do I use the linkedin gem(https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin)

I have installed the gem and understand about getting the actual profile data but the bit in the middle confuses me.

Where should the api key code block go ? should I be creating a seperate .rb file or should I call it at the top of the controller ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example linked in the readme shows them creating a separate controller to handle the authentication.

Check out the example [here](http://pivotallabs.com/users/will/blog/articles/1096-linkedin-gem-for-a-web-app)

Comment: this link is broken, got any other examples?